# How to change label colors in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, colors, highcharts, label

Why in this script label color still black?

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      color: ['#7cb5ec', '#434348'],
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color-attribute only accepts one color - if you wish to apply different colors to different series, you have to write your own "formatter"-function:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<span style="color:' + (this.series.name == "series1" ? '#7cb5ec' : '#434348' ) + '">' + this.y + '</span>';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Provide a name for your series and differentiate by the name to provide the correct color for the label.

For a working demo see here: http://jsfiddle.net/oa2dgwku/